# How to create unit test for Paperclip::Geometry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, paperclip, shoulda

I'm writing unit test for a image uploader that uses paperclip.
It's being bumpy and I was slowly moving thought the hurdles till I got stuck in the paperclip::geometry class

Here is my code below

```
 require 'test_helper'
 require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),"../../config/initializers","paperclip")    

 class PhotoTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
 #include ActionController::TestProcess

 should_belong_to(:product)
 should_have_attached_file :data

 setup do
   #I had to do this way because the include right below the class line was not working 
   image = Photo.create(:data => ActionController::TestUploadedFile.new(ActionController::TestCase.fixture_path + "base-production-pack.png",'image/png')) 
   @geo = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image)
 end
end
```

the paperclip::geometry is giving me the error:

```
test: Photo should have a paperclip attachment named #data. (PhotoTest):
Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: #<Photo:0x1054aa6b8> is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
paperclip (2.3.6) lib/paperclip/geometry.rb:24:in `from_file'
/test/unit/photo_test.rb:13
```

I have a initializer file "paperclip.rb" that points to the identify on my local machine

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`Paperclip::Geometry.from_file` expects a path, so you should do:

```
Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image.data.path)
```

Sidenote: It's good that you're testing, however there's little point testing paperclip's geometry method because paperclip's test suite covers that. Your tests should cover what *your* code is expected to do (eg confirming thumbnails are resized as expected).